# Url Routing is not working on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-6

Url Routing is not working on IIS 6. (using System.Web.Routing Namespace)

If i am running through VS 2008 then its working fine.
if i made virtual directory on IIS 6 then its not working.
its giving error 404 - file not found...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, only files with extensions that are associated with ASP.NET (.aspx, .ashx etc) are sent to ASP.NET. You need to enable wildcard mapping to make sure that URLs to folders are processed (and thereby, routed) by ASP.NET:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true